# How to calculate product of 2 fields with multi rows

Tags: javascript, html

i am using this code to calculate the product of 2 fields and there are many rows, when i use only one row the result is printing in input field. but when i use multiple rows of input fields the result is not printing into text box...
how can i this?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatesum() {
document.input.total.value = (document.input.time.value -0) * (document.input.cost.value -0);
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="input" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
Timespent:<input type="text" name="time" value=" ">
Cost:<input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">
Totalcost:<input type="text" name="total" value=" ">
<br>
Timespent:<input type="text" name="time" value=" ">
Cost:<input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">
Totalcost:<input type="text" name="total" value=" ">
<br>
Timespent:<input type="text" name="time" value=" ">
Cost:<input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">
Totalcost:<input type="text" name="total" value=" ">
<br>
Timespent:<input type="text" name="time" value=" ">
Cost:<input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">
Totalcost:<input type="text" name="total" value=" ">
<br>
Timespent:<input type="text" name="time" value=" ">
Cost:<input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">
Totalcost:<input type="text" name="total" value=" ">
<br>
Timespent:<input type="text" name="time" value=" ">
Cost:<input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">
Totalcost:<input type="text" name="total" value=" ">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="updatesum()">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function updatesum() {
var totalFields = document.input.time.length;
for(var i=0; i <= totalFields; i++){
    document.input.total[i].value = ( document.input.time[i].value * document.input.cost[i].value);
}
return false; }
```